# Ember js computed properties from model to view template?

Tags: ember.js

I'm wondering what is the proper way to use computed properties from a model in a view's template? Consider the following:

```
///
//MODEL//
////////////////////////////
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  imageDefault: DS.attr('string'),

  detailPic: function() {
    var url = this.get('imageDefault');
    var image = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var thumb = 'lg_' + image.substr(3);
    return url.replace(image, thumb);
  }.property('imageDefault'),
  });

 ///
 //VIEW//
 //////////////////////////////////////
 App.ItemDetailView = Em.View.extend({
   templateName: "itemDetail",
   //adt'l view logic...
 });
```

And here is the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="itemDetail">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pull-left item-detail-main-pic">
      <img {{bindAttr src="detailPic"}}>
    </div>

    test: {{controller.model.detailPic}}

</script>
```

So with the code above the view "ItemDetailView" will retrieve the first item object selected from the ArrayController "Items" and properly compute the detailPic from imageDefault property. The img src bind-attr will reflect the correctly computed img src and the handlebars {{controller.model.detailPic}} will properly display the same link.

However, when another item from the ItemsController (ArrayController) is selected the

```
<img {{bindAttr src="detailPic"}}>
```

will not update, but the test handlebars {{controller.model.detailPic}} in the view template WILL update.

I've tried the following variations with the same results.

```
//
<img bind-attr src=detailPic>

// 
<img bind-attr src=controller.model.detailPic>
```

What is the proper way to use computed properties in models in view templates? Or should it be avoided?

Comment: Your first thing is correct, can you set up a jsbin showing the issue?  What is actually updating?  What happens when you do {{detailPic}} instead of the controller.model.detailPic ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the test `{{controller.model.detailPic}}` works, try using that path instead:

```
<img {{bindAttr src="controller.model.detailPic"}}>
```

Also it is surprising that the test `{{controller.model.detailPic}}` works but `{{detailPic}}` does not. In most templates `controller` would be redundant since the controller is already the template's context. Then (assuming the controller is an ObjectController) `.model` would be redundant as well since the detailPic property would just proxy through. Try the following tests from that same template to see what is going on:

```
<pre>
this: {{this}}
controller: {{controller}}
controller.model {{controller.model}}
detailPic: {{detailPic}}
controller.detailPic: {{controller.detailPic}}
controller.model.detailPic: {{controller.model.detailPic}}
</pre>
```

Comment: Strange, when I change the {{bindAttr src="controller.model.detailPic"}} I still don't get the image url to update correctly. Also my detailPic and controller.detailPic values don't refresh, but if I were to use {{bindAttr src="detailPic"}} the controller.model.detailPic value doesn't refresh. So simply, whatever I use within "bindAttr" does NOT refresh once the view is loaded. I've done experiments where rerendering the view is the only way to get the update detailPic, but this doesn't seem ideal??? So is there no way to bind attributes from a model's computed property without rerendering???

Comment: For sure there is something wrong - bindAttr from a models computed property should update without rerendering, that's a very common use case and the whole point of bindings. If you make a jsBin that demos the problem i can help debug...

Comment: Thank you, I'll add a jsbin hopefully later today, but I did figure out how to make it work! I added an {{#if detailPic}} block around my markup where my {{bind-attr}} code was. I want to dig a little deeper and see if it's something that needs to be reported on github. Thanks again!